# What's the fastest websocket bitcoin provider to access mempool data?

Tags: nodes, mempool, websockets

I'm looking for a free or paid (reasonably) way to access the bitcoin mempool data by subscribing to the mempool. I'd like to get info in real-time, or anyway in the fastest way possible. Can anyone recommend how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) have a [API-WebSocket](https://mempool.space/docs/api/websocket).

You can obtain data of:

- `blocks`: last 15 block info, you can specify a particular block to obatian itself and 14 before blocks data.
- `mempool-blocks`
- `live-2h-chart`
- `stats`

It's not the best, but it works.
It depends on what you want, but the API-Rest is much better, has MORE data.